# sharepoint hosted apps and Angular Material Design Icons

Tags: angular, sharepoint, node-modules

I have the following setup...

1. Sharepoint Hosted App (Offline with no internet access)
2. Angular Framework 4.0.0
3. Angular Material 2.0.0 beta 3
4. Angular Material Design Icons

So far I have managed to get the Angular based app to work, but I am unsure how to do the following...

1. Use the Angular Material Icons within the app when using md-icon (Angular Material) and liturgy (e.g. home)
2. Reference libs or styles from node_modules without the need to copy them to the app folder

I would really appreciate the help with this one !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured out. All I needed to do was include the woff, woff2 and ttf files from Angular Material Icons within the app/css folder and voila it works.

Please find the files here...

https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/iconfont

download and include the following files...

1. MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf
2. MaterialIcons-Regular.woff
3. MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2